# How to typecast System.Windows.controls to Windows.UI.xaml.controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, composition

How to typecast System.Windows.controls to Windows.UI.xaml.controls in wpf. I want to uwp xaml control in WPF. Is this possible ? Below is my code:

```
 <Grid>
        <StackPanel  x:Name="AcrylicBackground" MinWidth="40" ></StackPanel>
        <Grid Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=AcrylicBackground}"
              Background="Transparent">            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

and

```
 ApplyAcrylicAccent(AcrylicBackground); \\ getting error here

...

private void ApplyAcrylicAccent(Panel panel)
{
   _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(panel).Compositor;
}
```

getting error as cannot convert from `system.windows.controls` to `Windows.UI.xaml.control`. please let me know how to type cast this ?

Comment: I believe there is a good chance you don't have to do this conversion, could you explain what you are trying to achieve with `_compositor` and this `ApplyAcrylicAccent` method ? Maybe there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Simply it is not possible.